# Print the nearby terms in Lucene Search

Tags: search, lucene

After making Lucene search my index using the IndexSearcher, how can I print the terms that are next to the search term.

```
QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("body", new StandardAnalyzer());
String queryStr = "search term";
Query q1 = qp.parse(queryStr);
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q1, 1);
System.out.println(hits.totalHits + " docs found for the query \"" + q1.toString() + "\"");
```

The above code just prints the search term if it exists, but I wish to print the terms next to the search term instead.

Comment: Take a look at [Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html).

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I used the highlighter to get the frags, then used a TokenStream which iterated to that frag, and then printed the next few tokens. Thank you for pointing it out.